# When a $0-1$-matrix with exactly two $1$’s on each column and on each row is non-degenerated? [2]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, permutations

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix with entries on the set $\{0,1\}$, with exactly two ones on each column and two ones on each row.

Give necessary and sufficient conditions for rank$(A)$ to be $n$.

I found two solutions in these two articles:

http://ge.tt/1x0JYek?c

but I really don't understand them, I was wondering if there is an easier way to solve this problem, or if you could explain to me the main idea of this articles in a less advanced and easier way, and/or **point out which exactly are the necessary and sufficient conditions**. Thank you.

(I know a matrix $A$ is non-signular if and only if rank$(A)=n$, that's why I think these articles can help).

Comment: It seems the linked paper shows that if $n=4$ there are no such matrices, but for other $n$ the paper constructs one such matrix. So the "necessary and sufficient" conditions (whatever they may be) must take special exception in the $n=4$ case.

Comment: It is a repeat, but I don't think the answer is good. Even the answerer states that "I don't think this completely answers the question."

Comment: See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/431184/1551) in another thread. The basic reason that no such matrices exist for $n=4$ is that $4$ cannot be written as a sum of positive odd integers that are larger than $1$.